# MVC ReturnUrl link error

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3

I'm working on ReturnUrl in mvc but I have some url link error.

`a href="/User/Login?returnurl=/Forum/Detail/@item.ID"`  with this link going to Login view and carrying returnurl parameters.

In the login page i catch returnurl querystring with this code

```
string url = Request.QueryString["returnurl"];

if (ModelState.IsValid)
{
    if (db.Users.Any(x => x.Mail == model.EMail && x.Password == model.Password && x.IsDelete == false))
    {
        FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(model.EMail, true);

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(url))
        {
            return RedirectToAction(url);
        }
        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
```

After when I click sign in I cannot go back to my first url. Link turn this `http://localhost:61476/User/Forum/Detail/3` (note: "User" is included in the URL)

I want to turn back this url: `http://localhost:61476/Forum/Detail/3`

Answer (score 0):

`RedirectToAction` (as you could imagine) redirects the user to an *Action*, and accepts an **Action Name** as parameter, but you are passing an URI to it.

Use `Redirect` instead:

```
if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(url))
    return Redirect(url);
```

Comment: It is same :( system going to this link again : http://localhost:61476/User/Forum/Detail/1   I want to go http://localhost:61476/Forum/Detail/1

Comment: Using the code you provided is not possible to further assist you. If using `Redirect` does not solve your issue then either your `url` variable is pointing to the wrong address or there is a problem not related to your current code (wrong IIS configuration, compile time errors, etc.).

Comment: I solve the problem the a href link must be like this a href="/User/Login?ReturnUrl=/Forum/Detail/@item.ID